# Issues with dynamically changing href attribute using dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a link using JavaScript which is based on user's inputs of two dropdowns. It works, however there are issues when the user goes back to change data on either of the dropdowns - it runs the script again and the link becomes something like `href="report_dayGU.phpJW.php"` instead of the desired `href="report_dayGU.php"`. If anyone could help resolve this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown-spans">
  <label for="reportSpans">Select Report Span:</label>
  <select id="reportSpans" name="reportSpans">
    <option value="#">Select</option>
    <option value="_day">Today</option>
    <option value="_week">This Week</option>
    <option value="_month">This Month</option>
    <option value="_all">All Records</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>

<div class="dropdown-aircraft">
  <label for="reportAircraft">Select Aircraft:</label>
  <select id="reportAircraft" name="reportAircraft">
    <option value="#">Select</option>
    <option value="GU">GU</option>
    <option value="JW">JW</option>
    <option value="NO">NO</option>
    <option value="SD">SD</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>

<div class="button-produce">
  <a id="report" href="#">Produce Report</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var span = document.getElementById('reportSpans');
span.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("report").href = "report" + this.value;
}

var ac = document.getElementById('reportAircraft');
ac.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("report").href = document.getElementById("report").href + this.value + ".php";
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sinesine/n8b7j78m/1/)

Comment: try replace penultimate line to this: `document.getElementById("report").href = "report" + document.getElementById('reportSpans').value + this.value + ".php";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the generation of the report hyperlink to a separate function, called by changes to either select box.

Example code is:

```js
var span = document.getElementById('reportSpans');
span.onchange = generateLink;

var ac = document.getElementById('reportAircraft');
ac.onchange = generateLink;

function generateLink () {
  var spanValue = document.getElementById("reportSpans").value;
   var aircraftValue = document.getElementById("reportAircraft").value;
   var reportLink = (spanValue != "#" && aircraftValue != "#")?("report" + spanValue + aircraftValue + ".php"):"#";

  window.alert(reportLink)
   document.getElementById("report").href = reportLink;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-spans">
  <label for="reportSpans">Select Report Span:</label>
  <select id="reportSpans" name="reportSpans">
    <option value="#">Select</option>
    <option value="_day">Today</option>
    <option value="_week">This Week</option>
    <option value="_month">This Month</option>
    <option value="_all">All Records</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>

<div class="dropdown-aircraft">
  <label for="reportAircraft">Select Aircraft:</label>
  <select id="reportAircraft" name="reportAircraft">
    <option value="#">Select</option>
    <option value="GU">GU</option>
    <option value="JW">JW</option>
    <option value="NO">NO</option>
    <option value="SD">SD</option>
  </select>
</div>

<br>

<div class="button-produce">
  <a id="report" href="#">Produce Report</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better build the href every time you change select value as below.

Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/cwcv8g99/)

```
var span = document.getElementById('reportSpans');
span.onchange = _updateUrl;

var ac = document.getElementById('reportAircraft');
ac.onchange = _updateUrl;

function _updateUrl() {
    var href = "report" + document.getElementById("reportSpans").value 
       + document.getElementById("reportAircraft").value
       + ".php"; 
  document.getElementById("report").href = href;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not seem correct because it is taking the value from the second dropdown even if it is not clicked. Do this test, click on the first drop down and click on the link without selecting the second top down. I cannot vote down as I am new but -1 from me for the selected answer.

Comment: @JVM I see you are correct, I'm going to change the selected answer. Thanks for highlighting that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have it like:

```
var span = document.getElementById('reportSpans');
span.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("report").href = "report" + document.getElementById('reportSpans') + document.getElementById('reportAircraft').value + '.php' ;
}

var ac = document.getElementById('reportAircraft');
ac.onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("report").href = "report" + document.getElementById('reportSpans') + document.getElementById('reportAircraft').value + '.php' ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done, check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n8b7j78m/3/):

```
https://jsfiddle.net/n8b7j78m/3/
```

I have put an alert to show the current href value.

```
var span = document.getElementById('reportSpans');
var baseURL;

span.onchange = function() {
baseURL = "report" + this.value;
document.getElementById("report").href = baseURL;
}

var ac = document.getElementById('reportAircraft');
ac.onchange = function() {
document.getElementById("report").href = baseURL + this.value + ".php";
alert(document.getElementById("report").href);
}
```

Comment: You were supposed to retain the previous value of the href before selecting the value from the second dropdown.

Comment: Please notice that your solution has a problem - whenever you select a value from the first select, it wipes out value of the second select from the href of the link - check it out here https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/453etvez/1/. I will not downvote your answer since you are a novice here.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, Thanks for being kind on me :). But, I don't think that is wrong. My idea was, when we select the first dropdown, we set a controller in the href, that could be a broader report or a report list. Even if the report link is clicked without setting the first dropdown, it would work. Not comparing solutions here but if we use the same function to generate URLs, we are forming a malformed URL with an extension .php just after clicking the first drop down.

Comment: Actually, if the first dropdown is only partially building the url and that url cannot function independently, the href should be set only after second dropdown is selected.